# Keyboard/Trackpad not working when Booted into LiveUSB

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, unix, trackpad

tl;dr
The Built-In Keyboard and Trackpad only works on 1st party bootable software but won't on anything 3rd party like linux. Model is MacBookPro12,1 (Early 2015, 13" Retina).

Keyboard and Trackpad *does* work on Apple 1st Party OS (Recovery, Diagnostics, macOS 10.14.6).

Keyboard and Trackpad does work in the Boot Selection Menu (option key on boot). Not sure if trackpad works on GRUB, and rEFInd, but keyboard does work on those two.

A List of all the Linux Distros I've Tested with the additional boot arguments `pci=noacpi noapic`;

- Ubuntu 20.04.2.0
- Ubuntu 16.04.7
- openSUSE Leap 15.3
- Fedora 32
- Fedora 34
- Fedora 30
- Arch Linux 2020.12.01
- Arch Linux 2021.09.01
- antiX 19.4

NVRAM/PRAM and SMC has been reset 3-4 times while testing if each distribution works.

Cable from the Logic Board to the Trackpad Control Board has been replaced, even though it still worked.

All cables connecting to the Trackpad Control Board have been reseated, if possible.

I have ran the built-in system diagnostics multiple times and on all occurrences there were no issues, only returned code `ADP000`.

Using an external Keyboard/Mouse does work on 1st party and 3rd party operating systems/system software but it's not viable for my situation.

Comment: Which touchpad driver did you install on Linux side?

Comment: I didn't install any touchpad driver, Previously (~3 months ago) key keyboard/trackpad suddenly stopped working on my fedora install with no updates since my laptop is never connected to the internet. I believe from 5.4.x there has been SMI and trackpad/keyboard support built into the linux kernel.

Comment: If the trackpad works in Recovery, it doesn't look like a HW issue. Can you install macOS from Recovery (doesn't matter which version), does the trackpad work there?

Comment: I currently have macOS 10.14.6 installed and the keyboard and trackpad work. But I do wish to switch back to linux if possible. **EDIT** The keyboard and trackpad *do* work in recovery mode.

Comment: If the trackpack works in macOS, it seems to be a Linux issue of some kind (and yes, I read the part about the laptop being offline the whole time).